# how to find the button id inside the Gridview which is in update panel?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

> i am not able to find the id of the update button is thee any way to
>   find the update button id which is inside the gridview and the grid is
>   inside the update panel.
>   Script register is written is page load. i am writing this so as
>   currently update button is firing on second click

**ASPX code**

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelSubMeter" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" Style="background-color: #B2DE94; width: 40px" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" OnClientClick="return fnCheck(this);" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**vb.net code**

```
     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Me.ErrorLabel.Text = String.Empty
            Me.ErrorLabel.Visible = False
            Dim pageName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
    If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
                tblNAbers.Visible = True
                BindBLDGDropDown("adonepudi")
            End If


          For Each gvr As GridViewRow In GridSubMeter.Rows
            If gvr.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim button As Button = CType(gvr.FindControl("btn_Update"), Button)
            If Not (button Is Nothing) Then
                                  ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterPostBackControl(button)

end sub
Protected Sub ddlBldgId_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ddlBldgId.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ddlBldgId.SelectedItem.Value != -1 Then
 BindGridSubMeter()
end sub
  Protected Sub BindGridSubMeter()
        Dim conMRI As New ConnectionMRI()
        Dim ds As DataSet = conMRI.NabersSubMetergetData(ddlBldgId.SelectedItem.Value, ddlRating.SelectedItem.Value)
        TextExclusions.Text = ds.Tables(1).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
        UpdatePanelExclusions.update()
        With GridSubMeter
            .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            .DataBind()
        End With
    End Sub
 Protected Sub GridSubMeter_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles GridSubMeter.RowEditing
        GridSubMeter.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
        Me.BindGridSubMeter()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridSubmeter_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e4 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridSubMeter.PageIndexChanging
        GridSubMeter.PageIndex = e4.NewPageIndex
        Me.BindGridSubMeter()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridSubMeter_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridSubMeter.RowUpdating
        Dim txtMeterIdn As TextBox = CType(GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtMeterIdn"), TextBox)
        Dim txCTFact As TextBox = CType(GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txCTFact"), TextBox)
        Dim txReadStartDate As TextBox = CType(GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txReadStartDate"), TextBox)
        Dim txReadEndDate As TextBox = CType(GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txReadEndDate"), TextBox)
        Dim txStartKwh As TextBox = CType(GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txStartKwh"), TextBox)
        Dim txEndKwh As TextBox = CType(GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txEndKwh"), TextBox)
        Dim txBillPer As TextBox = CType(GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txBillPer"), TextBox)

        Dim MeterIdn As String = txtMeterIdn.Text.Trim.ToString()
        Dim CTFact As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(txCTFact.Text)
        Dim ReadStartDate As Date = Date.Parse(txReadStartDate.Text)
        Dim ReadEndDate As Date = Date.Parse(txReadEndDate.Text)
        Dim StartKwh As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(txStartKwh.Text)
        Dim EndKwh As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(txEndKwh.Text)
        Dim billper As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(txBillPer.Text)

        Dim leasid As String = GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text.Trim.ToString()
        Dim suitid As String = GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text.Trim.ToString()
        Dim occupant As String = GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text.Trim.ToString()
        GridSubMeter.EditIndex = -1
        Dim conMRI As New ConnectionMRI()
        conMRI.NaberSubmeter(ddlBldgId.SelectedItem.Value, leasid, suitid, occupant, MeterIdn, CTFact, ReadStartDate, ReadEndDate, StartKwh, EndKwh, billper)
        Me.BindGridSubMeter()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Any error?????? and what you are trying to do with ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterPostBackControl(button)

Comment: update button is firing second time on clicking

Comment: On which event you are calling your code?

Comment: button is showing nothing

Comment: on pageload @Imad

Comment: can you post all code of pageload?

Comment: @Imad updated the code

Comment: Where did you writte `GridSubMeter.DataBind()`? after this code?

Comment: OT: `SelectedItem.Value` -> `SelectedValue`. Can you post only code we need?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
For Each gvr As GridViewRow In GridSubMeter.Rows
            If gvr.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim button As Button = CType(gvr.FindControl("btn_Update"), Button)
            If Not (button Is Nothing) Then
                                  ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterPostBackControl(button)
```

from page load and paste it in `BindGridSubMeter` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
For Each gr As GridViewRow In Grid_Records.Rows
Dim bt As Button = DirectCast(gr.Cells(0).FindControl("btn_Update"), Button)
Dim here As bt.properties
```

Next